# Can cp completely overwrite a directory?

Tags: rsync, cp

I'm wondering if there is a way to completely overwrite a directory that is being copied to without first needing to erase it with the rm command, meaning I don’t want to have files remaining in the destination directory that don’t exist in the source directory.  Is this possible with the cp command?  I would like results similar to the commands below but only by issuing one command.  I have tried rsync but I didn’t have any luck getting it to behave that way with it’s delete options.

```
rm -r /dest_dir/;  cp -a /source_dir/.  /dest_dir
```

Answer (score 7):

Command `rsync` in combination with --delete option, more in man rsync:

```
$ rsync -av --delete /from-path /to-path
```

Comment: I used rsync in my answer because your question has a rsync tag.

Comment: I tried that, but the test directory I had in the destination directory remained in place after issuing that command.  I’m surprised the cp command doesn’t have such a capability..

Comment: You have to make sure rsync has enough privileges to delete files in destination directory, try running it with sudo maybe. The example I gave you works for me on daily basis.